# Detecting tab change when using Android Navigation Component with Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I currently have an app (Java) that uses the Navigation Component with Bottom Navigation. I have a fragment for each tab.

One of the fragments navigates to a secondary fragment that features an audio player (using Media Player). This audi fragment has the following code that stops the audio when I go back to the parent fragment:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.pause();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the audio is playing and I tap on a different tab from the bottom navigation, the audio continues to play. I thought of using the following:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.pause();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

And this solves the problem but it also prevents the audio from playing when the screen is turned off. (This doesn't happen when the onStop is not there).

The idea is to have the pause() function execute when the user taps on any of the bottom navigation tabs.

With my current structure, how can I get the sound to stop when the user taps on a bottom tab?

Comment: Your MediaPlayer within a Fragment shouldn't continue to play when your app is closed or the screen turned off anyways (if you wanted that, you should be [following the guide to building an audio playback app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app) to avoid having Android kill your media playback while in the background), so `onStop()` seems like exactly the right approach for a Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "setOnItemSelectedListener()" to listen for clicks on Bottom Navigation.

If the user selects an item other than the one inside the audio player, stopAudioPlayer function is called

Example :-

```
navBottom.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {

       if (item.getItemId() != R.id.nav_bottom_audio_player)
          stopAudioPlayer();

       return true;
        });
```

Comment: Hi, I have a couple of questions. Where would this go? In MainActivity (in MainActivity I set up the bottom navigation for the Navigation Component)? If so, I don't have access to the fragment where the Media Player is because it's not part of the bottom navigation; it's a subfragment called by more than one of the bottom navigation options (so in your example I wouldn't have access to R.id.nav_bottom_audio_player). Also, how would I get access to the mediaPlayer in said subfragment from the MainActivity?